# Breaking a loop using TakeWhile when a count or length condition is meet

Tags: c#, linq

I'm  trying to figure out a way to use TakeWhile to break a loop when some conditions are meet.

i.e.

```
var i = 0;
List<IContent> t = new List<IContent>();

// children is a List<> with lots of items
foreach (var x in children)
{
    if (i >= 10)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (x.ContentTypeID == 123)
    {
        i++;
        t.Add(x);
    }    
}
```

What I'd like to do is to write that using Linq instead

```
var i = 0;
var a = children.TakeWhile(
    x =>
    {
        if (i >= 10)
        {
            break; // wont work
        }

        if (x.ContentTypeID == 123)
        {
            i++;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `TakeWhile` here - simply filter items which match your condition and take no more than 10 of matched items:

```
children.Where(x => x.ContentTypeID == 123).Take(10)
```

`TakeWhile` takes *all* items while some condition is met. But you don't need to take all items - you want to skip those items which don't have required `ContentTypeID`.

Comment: Wouldn't that iterate through the entire `children` list?

Comment: @EricHerlitz no, if you have more than 10 matched items. Exactly as your first loop did

Comment: Seems as if you are right, silly me to overcomplicate things

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer addresses the post.  This answer addresses the title.

TakeWhile and Take can be used together.  TakeWhile will stop on the first non-match and Take will stop after a certain number of matches.

```
var playlist = music.TakeWhile(x => x.Type == "Jazz").Take(5);
```